# Using IdentityServer4 with resource owner password grant

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am currently looking into IdentityServer4 to implement authentication for our Xamarin mobile apps to authenticate with our ASP.NET Core WebAPI, which would leverage  ASP.NET Core Identity for authorization.

So I would basically have three projects:

- IdentityServer
- WebAPI
- Xamarin App

Since API and Apps are all our own, I have decided to go with ResourceOwnerPasswordGrant. However, I am puzzled as to how I would implement registration.

Is it correct to assume, that all the actual account handling - registration as well as login - would need to be completely implemented within the IdentityServer project and not the WebAPI project?

How would I go about actually implementing that, considering the TestUsers from the Quickstart project is a massive shortcut to providing a functional login via ResourceOwnerPasswordGrant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was just published, pretty detailed and there are other options for authentication such as OpenIddict as well in a previous blog.

As for accounts, registration, and webapi entirely dependent on your setup requirements.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/01/23/asp-net-core-authentication-with-identityserver4/